# Paginate Shopify blog with offset? (Liquid)

Tags: pagination, shopify, blogs, liquid

I'm trying to figure out how to paginate a blog starting at a specific offset. For example, the first page features posts 5-8, the second page 9-12, third page 13-16, and so on. This doesn't seem to work, but I'm looking for something along these lines -

```
{% paginate blog.articles offset:4 by 4 %}

    {% for article in blog.articles

    ...

    {% endfor %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Are there any workarounds here?

Comment: There are a couple of ways I could think of to achieve this. Are you trying to always show the most recent 4 posts and then let pagination handle the rest?

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to see if there's any way I could find a *decent* workaround in Liquid but there isn't, since you're offsetting a full page; it'd be perfectly possible to show 5-8 on the first page, but you'd need to show 9-16 on second page and so on and so forth. I'm afraid Shopify `paginate` won't help you here.

There could be specific workarounds for your situation; please give us more detail and we'll see. For example, if you always want to show the four latest blog articles on every page, and leave pagination handle the rest, a possible way would be to do something as per the following:

```
{% for article in blogs.news.articles limit: 4 %}
  {{ article.title }}
{% endfor %}

{% paginate blog.articles by 4 %}
{% unless paginate.current_page == 1 %}
  {% for article in blog.articles %}
    {{ article.title }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endunless %}

{% include 'pagination' %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

So outside of any pagination go through the handle to obtain the latest 4 to feature them, and if you're not on page 1, use pagination to print 4 more articles on each page.

If not, this is one of the scenarios where you should consider exposing your own service that internally calls and retrieves articles [from the Shopify API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/article) as per your needs.

Comment: Hey Juan, I think this is really close. My scenario is that I only want posts 1-4 to appear on page 1, but the second part of this answer would work well.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand. If you're able to use my previous answer let me know, or if not tell me to see if we can find a solution. Cheers!

Comment: I believe your answer would show posts 1-4 on page 1, then 1-4 and 5-8 on page 2. I'm trying to offset the posts on each page by 4, so page 1 shows 5-8, page 2 shows 9-12, etc.

Comment: You can remove the snippet of the 1-4 posts, but you will not be able to show 5-8 unless you always link to `?page=2` on the url. That could work, but if not yeah, you'll need to go through shopify API

Answer (score 1):

The offset should be specified in your loop parameters, not in pagination.

Comment: This doesn't work in Shopify - the articles on each page are determined by the paginate object, so you would be offsetting from the available posts on every page.

Comment: It could be solve easily by adding a conditional statement for the loop offset if pagination = 1 offset, else do not.

Comment: When you use the paginate object in liquid, it predetermines the posts available on that page. Therefore, only posts 1-4 would be available on the first page, so offsetting by 4 would display no posts.

Comment: I understand, then you might capture loop you want (offset:4 limit:4 on the loop parameters) results before pagination.

Then, inside pagination, if page 1, display your capture content, and as else statement (page 2, etc), normal templating.

Do not forget to apply same offset on loop inside pagination to keep the flow.

Comment: I still don't think that would show the correct posts on pages 2+, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding. Feel free to update your answer with an example if you think it would work.