# Shopify Liquid: Different number of posts on first blog page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working in blog-template.liquid. I'm trying to show 13 articles on the first page of the blog with subsequent pages showing 12. My initial attempt was this:

```
{% if paginate.current_page > 1 %}
  {% paginate blog.articles by 12 %}
{% else %} 
  {% paginate blog.articles by 13 %}
{% endif %} 

 // Output articles...
{% endpaginate %}
```

This doesn't work because {% endpaginate %} must be paired with 'paginate' inside the if/else statement.

I've attempted the code below using variables but Shopify rejects the variable usage with 'Unknown tag 'num_articles'. Is there any way to have this statement accept and transform a variable to an integer – or is there a different solution I'm not thinking of? I'm somewhat new to Shopify and Liquid.

```
{% assign num_articles = 13 %}

{% if paginate.current_page > 1 %}
  {% num_articles = 12 %}
{% endif %} 

{% paginate blog.articles by num_articles %}
 // Output articles...
{% endpaginate %}
```

Comment: In the second example you're forgetting a 'assign'

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that.
`Pagination` tag works with the `for` tag to split content into many pages by setting the `limit offset`. This offset is fixed (constant) within pagination.

There are ugly work around and with [Shopify API](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront/2022-01/queries/blogs) you can try.  go search around for pagination offset.

https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/paginate

[Paginate Shopify blog with offset? (Liquid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852740/paginate-shopify-blog-with-offset-liquid)

https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussions/how-to-offset-the-second-page-in-a-collection/td-p/41939